# How do I merge two result sets without matching results getting multiplied?

Tags: merge, db2, cross-product

I have a query that returns a list of items and blank serial number fields like this:

```
Item  S/N
1        
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
. . .
```

The duplication is intended, as the number of rows for an item corresponds to the number of items purchased. I also have a table that contains items that have already received serial numbers:

```
Item  S/N
2     416
3     72
3     319
. . .
```

The query to build the first list does not reference the table with the serial numbers.
Now, I want to modify the result of the query with the information in the table
such that serial numbers from the table get added to the matching items. But, where there are not enough serial numbers, I want the blank serial numbers preserved (note that the table will never have more entries for an item than the query). The new result would look like this:

```
Item  S/N
1
1
1
2     416
3     72
3     319
3
3
. . .
```

I thought a left outer join would give me what I want, using my query results on the left (via a common table expression) and my table on the right. But when I tried it, this is what I got:

```
Item  S/N
1
1
1
2     416
3     72
3     72
3     72
3     72
3     319
3     319
3     319
3     319
. . .
```

It looks like the query performs a cross join on matching items, but preserves left side row cardinality when there is no match; not what I want. Is there a join or method I can use to get what I want?

Comment: Which database are you using? Please tag the question with the name of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t1.item, t2.s_n
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by item) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*
             row_number() over (partition by item order by item) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.item = t2.item and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: While I didn't use your exact solution, I was able to incorporate the row_number() function and your code into my common table expressions to arrive at the desired result. Thanks!